# HP Pavilion 360

Tags: laptop, 15.10, hp

I'm about to install Ubuntu 15.10 on a laptop HP Pavilion 360. I have right now Windows 10 as my only OS, and one of its functions is that, when I bend the laptop to use it as a tablet, the whole desktop or whatever application I'm using rotates according to the position of the laptop (I guess it uses a G sensor such as cell phones do). Is Ubuntu supporting the rotation function? If it does, how do I enable it? Or if not, how can I make it work?

Any help will be well received.

Comment: Why don't you test it in the installation media? Just select "Try Ubuntu without installing" when you boot it and test everything.

Comment: I just tried, but it seems it doesn't work. Anyway, thank you very much. Does anybody else knows how can I enable it?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a Thinkpad Yoga, i followed some untrustworthy guides online to set up something (a script) that auto-rotates the screen based on the accelerometer. But it wasnt a convenient thing and i dont have the link and i dont know if it would also work for the HP. But i think it is most probably possible to make it work. Maybe in the future theyll support it out of the box (i.e. without any effort from you).